# Koa start error

Tags: koa2

```
......\node_modules\koa\lib\response.js:47
const { res } = this;
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (......\node_modules\koa\lib\application.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

When I start my koa demo, console shows this.
node version: v4.4.7
"koa": "^2.2.0"
Here is my entry.js:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello Koa';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

After I remove {} in response.js:47 and context.js:124

```
const res = this;
```

everything runs ok.I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `const res = this;` mean just constant variable res equals this but 
`const { res } = this;` is object destructuring (http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html) it's equal `const res = this.res;` So if `this` has not property res you'll receive error.